# Does This Function Exist?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, analysis

I am trying to construct a piecewise function $g:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with

$g(0)=0,\hspace{3mm}$ $g \geq 0$, $\hspace{3mm}$  $\int_0^x g(t)dt\leq x,\hspace{3mm}$

and such that there is a sequence of disjoint intervals $\{I_n\}$, with $g=k_n$ constant on $I_n$, and $k_n\rightarrow  \infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, and $g=0$ outside of these intervals.

These intervals should approach $0$, so for e.g. $I_n=[1/4^n,2/4^n]$.

Of course $g$ does not have to be continuous, and there are no other requirements on $g$, just the above. Is this possible?

Comment: It is redundant to require length $(I_n)\to 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we take:
$$I_n=\left[\frac{1}{(n+4)^2}-\frac{1}{(n+4)^4},\frac{1}{(n+4)^2}\right],\qquad k_n=n+4$$
we have:
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{(n+4)^2}}g(x)\,dx=\sum_{N\geq n}\frac{1}{(N+4)^3}\leq\int_{n+3}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{t^3}=\frac{1}{2(n+3)^2}<\frac{1}{(n+4)^2},$$
hence all the constraints are fullfilled.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Intuitive:  If we ignore for now the requirement that $g(x)$ is constant on some intervals it seems $g(x)=\frac 1x$ on some intervals and $0$ on most of $(0,1]$ will meet the need.  We just need to make the intervals where it is $0$ long enough to meet the integral requirement.  Your set of intervals is a good start.  Let $g$ be constant on each interval.  If it doesn't increase too fast you will be there.

Comment: Yes, I was playign around w geometric series for a while. had difficulty getting the nice integral bound like wht Jack has above.